# How to create tuple from MaterialGroupMaster objects

Tags: python

I have a data structure like this :

```
[<MaterialGroupMaster: test>, <MaterialGroupMaster: test  material>, <MaterialGroupMaster: last>]
```

How would I get this as follows?

```
('test','test  material','last')
```

Comment: That is not a list of dictionaries. That looks like a list of *custom objects* instead. What attributes do the `MaterialGroupMaster` instances have that represents the value you want to extract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a list of dictionaries, you have a list of instances of a custom class instead.

To extract a specific attribute from each into a tuple, use:

```
tuple(ob.attribute for ob in inputlist)
```

Comment: I have tried this `materialMaster = get_list_or_404(MaterialGroupMaster)           
                abc = tuple(MaterialGroupMaster.name for MaterialGroupMaster in materialMaster)` , but it is saying `'MaterialGroupMaster' object is unsubscriptable`

Comment: @DibyenduDutta: Is this Django or another ORM? The error makes little sense; what is the full traceback? Would `materialMaster[0].name` work?

Comment: Sorry @Martijn Pieters It works perfectly , I am using Django . Also if i print `materialMaster[0].name` it is printing the first instance value i.e. `test`

Comment: @DibyenduDutta: Note that I am **not** using `for MaterialGroupMaster` in my answer; I was using a local name `ob` instead.

Comment: Yes @Martijn Pieters , i have changed it according to my instance name. I mentioned the code in first comment. Thanks a lot  :)